# Anatomy: name of the crease between leg and groin

Tags: anatomy, legs

What is the name of the crease/fold/sulcus between the top of the leg and the groin?

Here's an image:

[image: Image of the crease]

Comment: I just saw your edit @ShadowWizardisVaccinated and I'm curious. What does the edit you made do? I thought putting the image description in was enough for screen readers

Comment: @ChrisRogers I made the image smaller, it's still clear enough and doesn't take so much space. Might be just nitpicking, I wouldn't do it in old posts, just new-ish when I spot such thing. (Also note it links to the original size image)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 - I see. I was just curious as I saw how you edited it and didn't know what it did. I see it now. It's interesting 

Comment: @ChrisRogers yeah, lots of screenshots on Meta Stack Exchange where I usually roam (mostly bug reports), so learning some tricks. :)

Answer (score 1):

That crease is simply called the **crease of the groin**.
[See: [fig.1](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Skin-creases-of-the-human-body-a-Facial-creases-1-upper-eyelid-crease-2-nasolabial_fig1_237845357) of [Mallouris et al. (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00238-012-0774-3).]

Other names for this crease, as also indicated in the same paper include **Holden's crease** and **fold of the groin**

### References

Mallouris, A., Yiacoumettis, A., Thomaidis, V., Karayiannakis, A., Simopoulos, C., Kakagia, D., & Tsaroucha, A. K. (2012). A record of skin creases and folds. *European Journal of Plastic Surgery, 35*(12), 847-854. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00238-012-0774-3

Answer (score 1):

It also called inguinal crease and love line ...it denotes the inguinal canal and attachment of inguinal ligament ..also it is the junction of abdomen and thigh in either side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).